# grunt-processhtml like module for grunt 1.x.x

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

After upgrading to grunt 1.x.x from 0.4.x , processhtml task stopped working for me. On their github page, it is noted that "This plugin requires Grunt ~0.4.1".

I've tried to find a replacement, but could find nothing. Gruntjs github directory has several new version task packages going as grunt-contrib-... , but there seems to be nothing there to replace the old grunt-processhtml

What I basically need is an html processor that takes conditional tags such as

```
<!-- build:remove -->
```

into account and creates an html file for production use. What can I use for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found "grunt-html-build" (https://github.com/spatools/grunt-html-build) module to suit my needs. It has problems of its own, but it is grunt 1.x.x compatible and hopefully they'll solve the issues in time.